# FontaAwesome as a content to anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if that's the reason but everywhere i searched around the internet i've seen people use fontAwesome icons on solely on pseudoselectors. I want mine fontAwesome icon to appear as a content on a predefined .btn class.

Basically my code looks like this:

HTML

```
<a class="btn phone" href="#"></a>
```

CSS

```
.phone {
    font-family: 'fontAwesome';
    content: "\f095";
}

.btn { /*defined in another file*/ }
```

Code similar to this works on other anchors but I can't get it to work. I hope you understood my problem

Comment: The `content` property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

Comment: Ohhh, so it can't be used with other elements. Silly me

Comment: Correct! See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/adt394sp/

Comment: Thanks for cleering that out for me. I think someone already gave me a proper way to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the :before CSS selector. It is what creates the pseudo element.

```
.phone:before {
    font-family: 'fontAwesome';
    content: "\f095";
 }

 .btn { /*defined in another file*/ }
```

Comment: But I want the content to be inside the anchor and inside the predefined btn. I don't want to use pseudo element

Comment: You can't, the `content` property is only used with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: This solved my problem completly and thanks to Chris i know now what's
    content      property is used with

Answer (score 1):

> i've seen people use fontAwesome icons on solely on pseudoselectors. I want mine fontAwesome icon to appear as a content on a predefined .btn class.

The `content` property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. To answer your question, it won't work the way you're wanting it to. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/adt394sp/.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this `<a href="#" onclick="alert('see me work')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>`

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/w63ffsdn/

Comment: It is important for me not to have it within html and somebody already solved my problem. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7ev7071e/

```
.phone,
.phone:before {
    font-family: 'fontAwesome';
}
.phone:before {
    content: "\f095";
}

.btn { /*defined in another file*/ }
```